# How can I fix the relative path of imports inside NestJS project structure?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I'm [following](https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs) the [article](https://medium.com/swlh/create-an-api-rest-with-nestjs-1954723e8234) and I'm struggling with *imports* on the step with creating `UserService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm"; 
import { UserDto } from 'src/user/dto/user.dto'; 
import { Repository } from "typeorm"; 
import { UserEntity } from './../../entity/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UserService { 

constructor( 
@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity> 
}{}
 
create(user: UserDto): Promise<UserDto> {
   return this.userRepository.save(user); 
 }
 findAll(): Promise<UserDto[]> {
   return this.userRepository.find(); 
 } 
}
```

The problem is for lines:

```
import { UserDto } from 'src/user/dto/user.dto';
```

and specifically:

```
import { UserEntity } from './../../entity/user.entity';
```

[image]

Does anyone know what can be the cause of this problem? What can I fix from my side?

*UserDTO:*

```
import { IsNumber, IsString } from 'class-validator';
export class UserDto { 
@IsNumber() id: number;
@IsString() name: string;
@IsString() lastName: string; 
}
```

*UserEntity*:

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
@Entity() 
export class UserEntity { 

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn() 
id: number;

@Column({ nullable: false }) 
name: string;

@Column({ name: 'last_name', nullable: false }) 
lastName: string; 
}
```

In the project of the given article, *by the same principle*:

[image]

there are no any issues, but from my side I see errors related to the project imports.

Am I missing something? Do I need to add the absoluth path instead of relative?

There's the full [project structure](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/34b10748e94ef709d98ca7d67a8a8124#file-project-structure-L1).

I'm ready to provide more details if it helps to detect and fix the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dots inside folder names are generally not a good idea.
And try

```js
import { UserEntity } from './../../entity/user.entity/user.entity';
```

or even in a shorter way as:

```
import { UserEntity } from '../../entity/user.entity/user.entity';
```

and accordingly:

```
import { UserDto } from '../../dto/user.dto/user.dto';
```